# Whenever i try to use .map for fetching the data, i got error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

whenever i try to fetch the data with .map function is show me the error

```
user.map is not a function
```

> I use the below code for fetching the data

```
 user.map((user,index) => <>
         <h1> {user.name} </h1>
         <h1> {user.address} </h1>
     </>)
```

> And use the below code for getting the data from backend,

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState([
{
    name:'',
    phone:'',
    bgroup:'',
    pincode:'',
    address:''
}
  ]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/Donate").then(res=>{
        if(res.ok){
            return res.json();
        }
    }).then(jasonRes=>setUser(jasonRes));
},[])
```

> With this , i get data in console , when i use the below code

```
 console.log(user)
```

Comment: Is `jasonRes` an array?

Comment: .map wont work for json objects. you need to convert your response into array.

Comment: I think so, because it revert the data in array

Comment: Do you expect to have more than one user in `user`?  If not, then don't use map, because that would produce multiple "name" and "address" fields, which doesn't seem consistent with a single user.

Comment: I fetch the data from mongodb database , and there is more users, as there people come they register, and i want show them on specific page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
            
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/Donate").then(res=>{
        if(res.ok){
            return res.json();
             }
        }).then(jasonRes=>setUser(jasonRes && jasonRes.Donate));
    },[])
        
     return (
        <>
          {user.map((el, i)=> {
            <div key={i}>
               <h1> {el.name} </h1>
                <h1> {el.address} </h1>
              </div>
           })}
       </>
  )
```

Comment: I hope it finaly work